# jQuery 1.7.2 to 1.8.3, Google Maps broken

Tags: jquery, maps, migrate

I have the following code to load some Google maps.  I have upgraded jQuery from 1.7.2 to 1.8.3.  It broke, but I don't know where it is failing.  Code it below.  Is there some jQuery LINT type tool that I can use to debug these sort of migration issues?

No error in console.  The map simply did no show up at all. (I seem to have fixed it, though I'd like to understand the jQuery change)

```
var mcMapPage = null;
var mcGoogleScriptStatus = "";
var mcKmlStatus = "";



$(document).on("pageshow", '#map-show-page', function() {
// adjust content height to be page height - minus footer and header
var $page = $(this)
$page.find('[data-role=content]')
.height(
  $(window).height() - 
  ( $page.find('[data-role=header]').last().height() 
  + $page.find('[data-role=footer]').last().height())
);

loadMap($(this));
})


// split into load map and a callback to process after the google data is loaded
function loadMap(page) {
mcMapPage = page;  // store this so the callback can reference
mcGoogleScriptStatus = "loaded";

// could try looking for gstatic scripts, but this breaks if google changes, so   stick with
// looking for the initial js file
var scriptNode = document.getElementsByTagName("head") [0].querySelector('script[src^="http://maps.googleapis.com"]');
if (scriptNode == null) {
    mcGoogleScriptStatus = "loading";
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type="text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?  sensor=true&callback=postLoadGS";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
} else {
    if (mcKmlStatus != "loading") {
        mcKmlStatus = "loading";
        postLoadGS();
    }
}
 }

function postLoadGS() {
mcGoogleScriptStatus = "loaded";

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}   
var map = new google.maps.Map(mcMapPage.find('#map-div').get(0),mapOptions);
$(mcMapPage).data('map', map);

mcKmlStatus = "loading";
loadSelectedKml(mcMapPage);
}

function loadSelectedKml(page) {
// load active kml file
page = typeof page !== 'undefined' ? page : $.mobile.activePage;
var button = page.find('a.[data-role="radio-button"].ui-btn-active'),
    kmlUrl = button.attr('data-kml'),
    kmlLayer = page.data('kmlLayer');

if ( kmlLayer ) {
    // remove current layer from map
    try {
        kmlLayer.setMap()
    } catch (error) {
        // ignore it
    }
    page.removeData('kmlLayer')
}

if ( kmlUrl && kmlUrl != "") {
    var noCache = true
    if ( noCache )
    {
        var queryOperator = kmlUrl.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&"
        kmlUrl += queryOperator + "no-cache-value=" + new Date().getTime()
    }
    kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, {'preserveViewport': false})
    kmlLayer.setMap(page.data('map'))

    page.data('kmlLayer', kmlLayer)
}
mcKmlStatus = "loaded";
}

$(document).on('click', 'a.[data-role="radio-button"]', function() {    
loadSelectedKml()
return true
})

$(document).on("click", '#map-show-page div#map-div a', function(event) {
// intercept and open with MapController using System.open_url
var targetUrl = this.href

// JQM ajax likely hijacked, if so find the real target URL
if ( $(this).data('href') != undefined) {
    targetUrl = $(this).data('href')
}

// decide if this target url is to be opened externally
var doOpen = !(targetUrl == "" || targetUrl.indexOf("http:") != 0 ||
             targetUrl.indexOf("http://127.0.0.1") == 0 ||  targetUrl.indexOf("http://localhost") == 0 );

if ( doOpen ) {
    var openUrl = "/app/Map/system_open_url?target=" + encodeURIComponent(targetUrl)
    $.get(openUrl)
}

event.preventDefault();
return false;
})

$(document).on('scrollstop', '#map-show-page', function(event) {
// if the window scrolled, scroll it back to zero
if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 1) {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
}
})

$(document).on("pagebeforehide", '#map-show-page', function() {
mcKmlStatus = "";
})
```

Hmmm.. it seems as though the following is not supported anymore:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.[data-role="radio-button"]', function() {    
   loadSelectedKml()
   return true
})
```

If I change it to:

```
a[data-role="radio-button"]
```

it appears to work.  Can anyone expand on this jQuery change?  Was it a bug in jQuery, or have they changed way the selectors work?

Comment: What exactly *"broke"*? How is it broken? What is it doing or not doing?

Comment: If you don't know where it is failing, use your browser's JavaScript debugger to find out.

Comment: And ya, any error in console?

Comment: Your change is a correction... Possibly jQuery 1.7 interpreted that as "tag `a`, class `null`, data-role `radio-button`" while jQuery 1.8 saw "tag `a`, class `[data-role="radio-button"]`. As far as I'm concerned, jQuery 1.8 got it right.

Comment: `a.[attr=value]` doesn't make any sense. `.` is the start of a class selector, but then you didn't include any text for the class. That shouldn't have worked in any version.